# Insert an empty space in a txt output HP-UX

Tags: unix, echo, hp-ux

I need to insert a space line in a hp-ux script, that will generate a text output.
in that text file i will append 2 other text files and would like to have spaces between the input.

I have the test, test1 and test2 and use cat to append the content of test1 and test2 to test.

Could you please tell me what could help me? i tried echo, but i had no luck.

```
cat /home/cmorban/test1.txt >> /home/cmorban/test.txt
cat /home/cmorban/test2.txt >> /home/cmorban/test.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did `echo ""` not work for you?

Comment: hi Neil...just found and answer...thanks for asking. i am new to unix world :) it seems this does the job:echo >> /home/cmorban/test.txt; cat /home/cmorban/gbs.txt >> /home/cmorban/test.txt

Comment: Ciprian please mark answer as accepted if it is suitable for you...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through "echo" in between file write commands. So the code will be like follows.

```
cat /home/cmorban/test1.txt >> /home/cmorban/test.txt
echo "" >> /home/cmorban/test.txt
cat /home/cmorban/test2.txt >> /home/cmorban/test.txt
```